# Matching IP address with authorizeHttpRequests

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've read in [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html) that AuthorizationFilter supersedes FilterSecurityInterceptor. So I'm trying to migrate my application to this newer method.

I have something like

```
                http.authorizeRequests()
                        .mvcMatchers("/")
                        .hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1")
```

According to the linked page I should be able to write something like

```
                http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                        .mvcMatchers("/")
                        .access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')")
```

but there's no `access(String)` method. I even tried to paste verbatim code from the documentation:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize                                  
            .mvcMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()         
            .mvcMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                             
            .mvcMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")   
            .anyRequest().denyAll()                                                
        );

    return http.build();
}
```

which does not compile for the same reason.

Here's compilation error:

```
Application.java:103:55
java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationManager<org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestAuthorizationContext>
```

How do I use authorizeHttpRequests with IP addresses or string expression? Is it issue with documentation?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0 and Spring Security 5.7.1

Comment: What is the compiler error you get.

Comment: @M.Deinum added compilation error

Comment: Hmm. Thats weird, the docs state that it should work, the javadoc clearly indicates that there is no `access(String)` method. Appears to be an omission somewhere. I would create an issue in the spring security bug tracker as it is either wrong documentation or missing code.

Comment: Is it possible to use hasIpAddress with spring security 6 ?

Comment: ciao @lucas, no it is not i myself has been struggling. the only thing i foud that remotely works: `http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
       
            authorize.requestMatchers(request -> isIpAddressMatch(request, "11.11.11.11")).permitAll();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does appear to be an issue with the docs. There is not currently a built-in implementation providing the `hasIpAddress(String)` access check, but you can use the `IpAddressMatcher` class to implement an `AuthorizationManager` capable of performing it.

Here's an example configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
                .requestMatchers("/").access(hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1"))
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    private static AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> hasIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        IpAddressMatcher ipAddressMatcher = new IpAddressMatcher(ipAddress);
        return (authentication, context) -> {
            HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
            return new AuthorizationDecision(ipAddressMatcher.matches(request));
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prescribed way as per [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_migrate_hasipaddress_to_accessauthorizationmanager) is as below.

```
IpAddressMatcher hasIpAddress = new IpAddressMatcher(ipAddress);
authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/your/url/**")
    .access((authentication, context) ->
        new AuthorizationDecision(hasIpAddress.matches(context.getRequest())));
```