# Whitelisting ip in Spring >6.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

I am trying to understand how whitelisting works inside Java Spring Boot >6.1.

Below you can see my class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // definie the encripter
        return new BCryptPasswordSimpleEncoder();
        //  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // Define a custom method to check the IP address
    private boolean isIpAddressMatch(HttpServletRequest request, String ipAddress) {
        IpAddressMatcher ipAddressMatcher = new IpAddressMatcher(ipAddress);
        return new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/**").matches(request) &&
                ipAddressMatcher.matches(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
            // Whitelist specific IP for /rest/**
            authorize.requestMatchers(request -> isIpAddressMatch(request, "11.11.11.11")).permitAll();

            // Other configurations
            authorize
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/*.png"))
                    .permitAll();

            // Icons from the line-awesome addon
            authorize
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/line-awesome/**/*.svg"))
                    .permitAll();

            // Authorize other /rest/** requests
            authorize
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/**"))
                    .permitAll();
        });

        http.csrf(csrf ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/**")));

        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }
```

Testing with Postman, I'm making a post request with the URL localhost:8080/rest, it always gives me 200 as a result unbothered by what IP I've put inside my `isIpAddressMatch(request, "11.11.11.11")`.

Looking at the documentation, it is unclear to me what I have to do, it looks like the `csrf` method overrides the restriction I've put for my IP address, so any value I enter is rendered useless.

Someone pointed out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72366267/matching-ip-address-with-authorizehttprequests) to me, but many of the method used in the link provided are not viable in Spring >6.1, like `mvcMatchers` is deprecated now, and the answer make use of `authorizeRequests` which is deprecated as well.

Comment: Also i might add that in the documentation for the ip whitelisting from the [5.8.8](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_migrate_hasipaddress_to_accessauthorizationmanager) does not have a clear corrispondance to the 6.1.3

Comment: If things are deprecated, they still work (but are expected to be removed in the future). Generally, the Javadoc of those methods will contain information on what their replacement would be.

Comment: Also, the documentation you link from 5.8.8 shows what the replacement of the method `hasIpAddress` **is** (they just confusingly gave the `IpAddressMatcher` also the name `hasIpAddress`), so follow that instruction. Construct an `IpAddressMatcher`, and use it from the `access` method within `authorizeHttpRequests` (as opposed to `authorizeRequests`) as shown in that link (but also consider the note below that code, which basically says it is a bad idea to do this).