# Getting Access Denied for all routes (with PermitAll() ) in Vaadin 24 and Azure SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, vaadin, java-17, vaadin-flow

I'm trying to get Azure SSO working with a Vaadin app.
I have been reading the docs but I'm still doing something wrong as I'm getting the Access Denied page with the message.

> Could not navigate to ''
> Reason: Access is denied by annotations on the view.
>
> Available routes:
>
> - ...
>   All my pages are the same.

I have configured my `application.properties` with the relevant data:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT ID]/v2.0
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.[MY APP].provider=azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.[MY APP].client-id=[CLIENT ID]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.[MY APP].client-secret=4[CLIENT SECRET]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.[MY APP].scope=profile,openid,email
```

I have got to my SSO page and logged in and then when the redirect happens I get the error.

I have also got the dependency in my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
```

I have defined the Security Config as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
            auth.requestMatchers(
                AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/**")).permitAll());
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

And at the top of my views I have, for example the default route:

```
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Home")
@PermitAll
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I needed was actually:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[i had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77310172/whitelisting-ip-in-spring-6-1)
beacuse the Spring boot security documentation is not easy to navigate.

Try with the solution that worked for me:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {

            authorize
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"))
                    .permitAll();
    
      });

        http.csrf(csrf ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth2/authorization/**")));

        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }
```

The documentation from 5.8.8 shows what the replacement of the method `hasIpAddress` is (they just confusingly gave the `IpAddressMatcher` also the name `hasIpAddress`), so follow that instruction.
Construct an `authorizeHttpRequests` as shown in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_migrate_hasipaddress_to_accessauthorizationmanager) also consider the note below that code, which basically says it is a bad idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set the views with @PermitAll if you already did in security config? Also, I would extends OAuth2UserRequestAwareWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instead of VaadinWebSecurity for pre-defined atributes of your case.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends OAuth2UserRequestAwareWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("@myUserDetailsService.hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try and then report back.

Comment: You're right - I don't need .PermitAll() I am removing

Comment: Good! Please assess the responses and verify their effectiveness by accepting the most suitable solution. This ensures that the best approaches are acknowledged and can be reused by the community.